# Custom stat aggregation and sorting function in solr

Tags: solr, aggregate-functions, solr4

Please provide suggestion/example to create a custom stat[Aggregate] function in the Solr.
Every document in Solr is having 30 String, 10 int and 1 binary[hashset to store unique users] fields.
I want to add a new stat function (UniqueUsers(fieldName) like add/avg function already available in Solr) to find the unique across searched Solr records.

While googling, i found following Issue ticket SOLR-5302 ,which is already resolved ,but i dint find any example to implement it.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5302

Answer (score 2):

Solr already has a stats component that does aggregation and combines it with facets.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component

If this doesn't do exactly what you need, you can copy that source code file (and any that it references which need changes) to your own custom component and compile a new project against the Solr jars that you can find in the dist/ directory of the download.  I don't have precise instructions for doing this -- the person who sets that up must have extensive knowledge of how to build Java development projects.  Then you must inform Solr about the new Component and use it in your request handler, by modifying solrconfig.xml.

The trunk version of the Solr source code already includes a new and more capable AnalyticsComponent - SOLR-5302.  Because it is missing a little bit of functionality already present in the StatsComponent, I don't think it is available in a released version of Solr yet.  You're welcome to take the patches and do the manual work that may be required so they work with a 4.x version.